# Why TText Trimming does not work when WordWrap is enabled in Firemonkey?

Tags: android, firemonkey, rad-studio

I'm using Rad Studio 10.2.3. In my form when I have a TText with long content, I set WordWrap property to "True" and Trimming property to "Word".
In design time everything looks good but in runtime and in android platform there is a problem as shown in the picture:

[image: the screenshot of my problem]

What should I do to avoid this?

Update:

I installed RAD Studio 10.3 Rio and tried again. Now the meaningless characters are gone but the trimming problem is still there, just like the image below:

[image]

Comment: If you don't have yet RIO you can also try TALText from https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe that is much faster than TText and support even basic HTML tag

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll gonna give it atry and give you the feedback.

Comment: I installed the components and TALText did ok. It is really faster and there is no bug anymore. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @loki Your recommendation helped me to solve the problem. Post it as an answer so that I accept it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug and it has been fixed in 10.3 Rio.

See: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20529

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm on for installing Rio a testing the case.

Comment: I installed 10.3 Rio. Meaningless characters below the TText do not exist anymore but the text within the TText is not trimmed yet. So the problem is not completely resolved in 10.3 Rio.@hans

Comment: @Moj.H Your question only mentions the meaningless characters at the bottom. The trimming in your image is already correctly by "Word" as your settings specifies.

Comment: Thats right! By using 10.3 Rio the meaningless characters were gone. But another problem showed up! When the Trimming property is set to "word" or "character", it does not work. I will update my post and upload another screen shot showing the problem asap. @Hans

Comment: And something else! The trimming in my image is NOT correctly done by "word". There should be three dots ( ... ) at the end of the text. @Hans

Comment: This bug still exists in 11.0